# No sound when plugging in headphones

Tags: release-freya, sound

I have a problem which really bugs me. My laptop speakers work perfectly, but whenever I plug in my headphones, there's just no sound. Nothing is muted, my settings are good, so I really don't know why this happens. I also have Windows installed on my laptop, and whenever I plug them in while running Windows, they work. (I use freya)

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and/or a solution? Thanks.

Comment: In a terminal type `alsamixer` it will bring up a graphic equaliser where you can adjust the volume for the headphone independently from your speakers. You may have to press F6 to choose your soundcard. I would assume the *headphone* levels are muted (depicted with a MM). Your headphones may be listed as AUX. Failing that, do you have 'Beats Audio' or any special brand name speakers on your laptop?

Comment: This comment should really be an answer so other people with similar problems can find a (likely) solution more easily :)

Answer (score 1):

This screenshot is from the Loki release, so it might be a little different, but you can adjust your sound settings from `System Settings > Sound`. Make sure your sound isn't all the way down and try jumping between the different outputs and using the "Test Sound" button to make the audio play back. (In Loki, the new release, you can do some of this direct from the icon in the OS's upper-right corner.)

[image: Sound]

If this doesn't solve your issue, try posting more specific information on what you have tried and what isn't working as expected.