# Why has sound stopped to work on headphones?

Tags: release-freya, sound

I'm using freya 3.2 and after installing TLP Advanced Power Management the audio jack isn't working anymore. The strange thing is that the notebook's loudspekakers are working regularly (when headphones are not plugged in). Also, the headphones are working in other devices.

In Detail, what I did between sound-working and sound-not-working was to install tlp and tlp-rdw as described in [this post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/how-to-optimize-elementary-os-for-maximal-battery-life-time-on-laptops/1091#1091). I also installed gksudo, which didn't work properly, thus I purged it again.

I have a Dell XPS 13 (2015). Does anybody have an idea where to start investigating the cause, or maybe even a solution?

**EDIT:**
Headphones are recognized and selected, but sound doesn't work.

[image: settings sound]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found this [question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/865/no-sound-when-plugging-in-headphones) which is very similar and has a solution in a [comment](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/865/no-sound-when-plugging-in-headphones#comment1524_865)..

The solution is to activate the correct sound card in the `alsamixer` equalizer. This can be done by typing `alsamixer` in a terminal and using `F6` to choose a sound card.

If speakers, headphones, mics, etc. are muted, this can also be changed with the alsamixer equalizer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check under `System Settings` > `Sound` > `Output` tab, the output source, while you have plugged your headphones in ? I assume that wrong output is selected.

Comment: As soon as I plug in the headphones, they are selected. When I select internal audio as output, the sound works again. Do you have other ideas or does selected in this context mean something else?

Comment: I 'm sorry, I don't have access to eOS right now. Can you add a screenshot of sound settings > output  ?

Comment: I edited the question. Now there's a screenshot.

Comment: There are so many reports regarding dell xps sound card problems. Do you dual boot eos/windows ?